# Finding the roots to $x^4 + \sqrt{3x^2} - 7 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So when I plug in:

$$x^4 + \sqrt{3x^2} - 7 = 0$$

I get the roots as: $x = 1.45$ and $x = -1.45$

Somehow that's wrong, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: How did you get those roots?

Comment: Is the middle term supposed to be $\sqrt{3x^2} = \sqrt{3}|x|$ or $\sqrt{3}x^2 = x^2\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Well, I edited it as the same way how he wrote it.

Comment: I cannot imagine the problem of finding the roots of $f(x)=x^4+\sqrt{3x^2}-7$ being assigned in precalculus.  On the other hand, finding the roots of $g(x)=x^4+\sqrt{3}\cdot x^2-7$ should be very doable via the substitution $x^2=y$ and solving first for the roots of $y^2+\sqrt{3}\cdot y-7$ via the quadratic formula.  The first problem would require solving $x^4+\sqrt{3}\cdot x-7$ for its roots, checking if positive, and then solving $x^4-\sqrt{3}\cdot x - 7$ and checking if negative.  Neither seem easily solved by hand.

Comment: Further, the [education](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) tag is not to be used because you are learning the material... the tag should only be used in relation to asking questions about the *process of educating* or of the educational system in general.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, I will keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: Since you have two solutions because $\sqrt{3x^2}=\pm 3x$, the first equation is $x^4+\sqrt{3}x-7$. The second is $x^4-\sqrt{3}x-7$. Both equations let me approximations of the solutions, just like the ones obtained by Euler_Salter. I can't get exact numbers expressed in rational or roots of naturals.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois As mentioned already a number of times $\sqrt{3x^2}=3|x|$.  It does not ever equal a negative number.  Saying $\sqrt{3x^2}=\pm 3x$ is in my opinion confusing as it is only ever one of those at a time, never both (except when $x=0$).  $\sqrt{3(5^2)}=\sqrt{3}\cdot 5$ but $\sqrt{3(-2)^2}=-\sqrt{3}\cdot(-2)$

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you were saying. You're saying about the absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a typo or a misunderstanding has occurred and the intended problem to solve for the roots is in fact $f(x)=x^4+\sqrt{3}x^2-7$  (*note the difference between $\sqrt{3x^2}$ and $\sqrt{3}x^2$*)

Step 1: Substitute $y$ in for each occurrence of $x^2$

$f(x)=x^4+\sqrt{3}x^2-7 = y^2+\sqrt{3}y-7$

Step 2: We find the roots of this expression in terms of $y$ using the quadratic formula: $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}\pm \sqrt{3+28}}{2} = \dfrac{-\sqrt{3}\pm \sqrt{31}}{2}$

We note however that $y=x^2$ cannot be negative, so the only root that works is the positive one, $\frac{-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{31}}{2}$

Step 3: Now, solving $x^2=\frac{-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{31}}{2}$ we get $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{31}}{2}}$ as two real roots of the equation.

From calculus, we see that as the second derivative is strictly positive, there can only be at most two real roots, so the remaining roots will be complex.

Comment: Thank you, I will double check with my teacher, really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3882522 if it truly was intended as written, there does exist a [closed form expression](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg) for solving [general quartic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), but noone bothers learning or using it except via computer.  [Methods exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for approximating roots of "well behaved" functions, but as this is labeled precalc you would not be ready for such techniques.

Answer (score -2):

No those are correct, you have:
$ x^4 + \sqrt{3}x-7 = 0$. Hence the roots (using Wolfram Alpha) are $x_1 = 1.4549$ and $x_2 = -1.4549$.

Comment: $x \neq \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

Comment: I put that as the answer.. it said it was wrong.

Comment: Actually, Wolfram Alpha gives $1.4549$ and $-1.4549$ as the roots of $x^4+\sqrt{3x^2} - 7 = 0$, which is exactly the equation stated in the question. Perhaps $1.45$ and $-1.45$ do not give enough digits of precision, perhaps the equation was incorrectly copied, perhaps the answer key is wrong. There is too little detail given to say which.